# Horizontal forces when pushing a box against the wall:

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If one's hand pushes a box against a wall, aren't there two forces acting in opposition? Wouldn't it be the normal force from the wall acting on the box and the reaction force from the box to the hand?

Answer (score 1):

There are some vocabulary and concepts to straighten out.

Forces occur in equal and opposite pairs. If object A pushes on object B, B pushes back on A. This in Newton's 3rd law.

In this case, if your hand pushes on the box, then the box pushes back on the hand. If the box pushes on the wall, the wall pushes back on the box.

Sometimes the push back force is called a reaction force. This happens when A pushes on a rigid B. If B was a liquid, A could penetrate into the interior of B. But if B is rigid, B exerts a force that is just strong enough to prevent this. If your hand pushes hard on a wall, the wall pushes back equally hard. This is just hard enough to stop the hand. If you just barely touch the wall, the wall just barely touches back. Again just hard enough to stop the hand.

Often you are interested in the total force on an object. In this case, it appears to be the force from the hand and the force from the wall. Since the box is motionless (in particular, it is not accelerating), we know the total force is $0$. This implies the force from the hand and the force from the wall are equal and opposite.

It often happens that the total forces on and object is $0$. If there are two forces, this does not mean a these forces are each other's other half from Newton's law, necessarily equal and opposite. For example, suppose two people push on opposite sides of the box. If they happen to push equally hard, the box will not accelerate. But if one is stronger, the box will accelerate.